# Custom Navigation Controller in an MVVMCross App

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on an MVVMCross based app and need to use a custom `UINavigationController` but I'm struggling to see how I can do this as I can't see the point at which the navigation controller is created.

Can anyone give any guidance on how a custom `UINavigationController` can be used within MVVMCross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do that in your own Presenter by overriding `CreateNavigationController`:

```
protected override UINavigationController CreateNavigationController(UIViewController viewController)
{
    var toReturn = base.CreateNavigationController(viewController);
    toReturn.NavigationBarHidden = false;
    toReturn.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(15, 79, 140);
    toReturn.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(228, 242, 231);
    toReturn.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
    return toReturn;
}
```

Modify as needed. `base.CreateNavigationController` just creates an instance of `UINavigationController`.